# deploy router status Pending

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

By the following composition, openshift-origin, using playbook in ansible, the environment was built.

```
[node]
openshift-master.example.com<br>
openshift-node01.example.com<br>
openshift-node02.example.com<br>
openshift-etcd.example.com<br>


[/etc/ansible/hosts]
[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
etcd

# Set variables common for all OSEv3 hosts
[OSEv3:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=root
deployment_type=origin

[masters]
openshift-master.example.com

[etcd]
openshift-etcd.example.com

# host group for nodes, includes region info
[nodes]
openshift-master.example.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'infra', 'zone': 'default'}"
openshift-node01.example.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'east'}"
openshift-node02.example.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'west'}"
```

In following command, in openshift, login, oh, it was done.

```
 [login command]
 oc login -u system:admin -n default
```

And Replica in router, it was made in following command.

```
 [create router command]
 oc scale dc/router --replicas=2
```

The following event occurs, and a place can't make replica in router.

```
 [create router command]
 Failed scheduling  
 pod (router-2-ievkl) failed to fit in any node fit failure on node (openshift-node01.example.com): CheckServiceAffinity fit failure on node (openshift-node02.example.com): CheckServiceAffinity fit failure on node (openshift-master.example.com): PodFitsHostPorts
```

It's such situation, but when how doing correspond, would I be able to make replica in router right?

Comment: I THINK (I'm not sure) that the problem here is the following. You can perform `oc get nodes` and I think you'll node (on the same machine as your master) will be unschedulable. This means the scheduler will not assign pods to that node. It's the node with the as lable: `region:'infra'`. Now I'm not sure if registry/router pods etc are automatically deployed on nodes which have the label `infra`. If it is, that could be the issue. It needs to create pods on a node with label infra but the node with the infra label is  unschedulable. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Got the same issue after clean install of origin.
Uncordoning masters do the thing. Thnx to lorenzvth7

> During advanced installation, the openshift_hosted_router_selector and openshift_registry_selector Ansible settings are set to region=infra by default. The default router and registry will only be automatically deployed if a node exists that matches the region=infra label.

Also, according to an error topic starter's case "**PodFitsHostPorts**"

> Routers directly attach to port 80 and 443 on all interfaces on a host. **Restrict routers to hosts where port 80/443** is available and **not being consumed** by another service, and set this using node selectors and the scheduler configuration. **As an example, you can achieve this by dedicating infrastructure nodes to run services such as routers**.

So, this means that you shoul re-label e.g. openshift-node01.example.com as region:infra